# ExpressJS app login fails after saving first login history

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I've implemented a ExpressJS app using PassportJS, MongoDB (Mongoose) and JSON web tokens.

Inside successful login route implementation

```
await user.insertLoginTime();
const token = user.generateJwt();
res.status(200).json({ token });
```

Mongoose model method 'insertLoginTime'

```
userSchema.methods.insertLoginTime = async function() {
  try {
    const presentTime = new Date().getTime();
    await this.loginHistory.push(presentTime);
    await this.save();
    return;
  } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

First login is successful and 'Postman' receives token but returns invalid password error over next attempts.

Removing the 'insertLoginTime' method successfully logs-in on multiple attempts. Is there any mistake in the 'insertLoginTime' implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue. It was occurring because I added password hashing to Schema 'pre' hook for 'save'. On saving login history, the hashed password was being hashed again and saved back. This was deleting the actual password hash and causing next attempts to fail.